# Google ads API Query returns _StreamingResponseIterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get reports for my google ads and display them on a dashboard for easier viewing and monitoring.

I've gone through the whole process to authenticate my account. I got all the keys needed.
Everything works up until the query is run. See code below copied from [Google ads API examples](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/get-campaigns)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright 2020 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
"""This example illustrates how to get all campaigns.

To add campaigns, run add_campaigns.py.
"""


import argparse
import sys

from google.ads.google_ads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.google_ads.errors import GoogleAdsException


def main(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v6")

    query = """
        SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name
        FROM campaign
        ORDER BY campaign.id"""

    # Issues a search request using streaming.
    response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id, query=query)

    try:
        for batch in response:
            for row in batch.results:
                print(
                    f"Campaign with ID {row.campaign.id} and name "
                    f'"{row.campaign.name}" was found.'
                )
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(
            f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
            f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
        )
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GoogleAdsClient will read the google-ads.yaml configuration file in the
    # home directory if none is specified.
    google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Lists all campaigns for specified customer."
    )
    # The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
    parser.add_argument(
        "-c",
        "--customer_id",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        help="The Google Ads customer ID.",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(google_ads_client, args.customer_id)
```

Nothing gets printed to my console. When I print out `print(response)`
i get `<google.api_core.grpc_helpers._StreamingResponseIterator object at 0x7fb7dcaaf3d0>`

I get no errors, tracebacks nothing. This is what my console looks like (hiding customer_id):

[image]

Comment: looks like everything is running fine. Is it possible that your google ad account has no campaigns?

Comment: try printing `len(response)` and check if it is 0.

Comment: @RitwikG Yes, my companies google ad account has 50+ campaigns. That's why I find it odd that it's not able to print any.

Comment: @RitwikG TypeError: object of type '_StreamingResponseIterator' has no len()

Comment: can you try `print(list(response))`

Comment: That returns an empty list "[]", Do you think because I'm using a manager google ad account that its not able to grab the campaigns? Google recommend using a manager acount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230112/discussion-between-ritwik-g-and-clarkefl).

Comment: MCCs don't have campaigns, only accounts do. You need to pass the actual account ID, not your MCC ID.

Comment: @DaveDavis ill give that a crack and see.

Answer (score 1):

It actually returns the value and you can use it.

```
 for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        print(
            f"Campaign with ID {row.campaign.id} and name "
            f'"{row.campaign.name}" was found.'
        )
```

Comment: For me, it is not returning any value. Program runs, nothing is printed. Meaning there are no results from the query. Yet there are multiple campaigns on the account which is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to a managerial account that doesn`t have actual campaigns. TO fix it you should get access to customer accounts. More information you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/login-customer-id)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31746428)